# Store data in the list - save it to list itsef for CSR to read

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-list, solution-package, jslink, client-side-rendering

I would like to ask if somebody has an idea how I can store formatting data for particular list/webpart on a page. My concept: I would like to create JSlink that would be attached in masterpage file. This JSlink would post render some visual to all lists with some controls. I would like to enable user to click on this post render controls change few settings and then save it with different settings for each list. I can do all of this, except SAVING actual data.

Image I would like let user to change a column color from red to green via this script but then I need to save it somewhere for that webpart/list view. 
Right now, I can only think of saving it as XML in form of a cookie for user, but I need these changes to be visible to everybody after somebody edits it, so cookies are not the right way to go.

Is there any way, how I can attach some sort of "cookie" to that particular view?

Comment: Someplace where your 'editors' have write access. If it is per View you could create one list with the ViewID as Title and the data in a JSON Object (description). I am working on something similar. A IKEA approach to creating CSR files (*but saving CSR files to the Style Library using Cisar and only for users/designers with write access to the Style Library*) which will be public in a couple of weeks. Contact me at danny@e2.nl and I'll give you access to the Github project